# Java call performance vs search performance

Tags: java, performance

Currently my program is filled with many ugly references that often make field or method access look like this: `weakReference1.get().weakReference2.get().field1.getSomeCustomObject().field2`. I want to move to shorter and faster strong references like `field1.field2`. But my program design is such that I will also have to go for an `ArrayList` element-by-element search (in a for-loop) instead of accessing a `WeakHashMap` by `get()` method.

Thus, I'd like to understand, can moving to simpler references compensate for rejecting `HashMap` performance wise. Herewith I presume that `WeakHashMap.get()` is much faster than a loop-search of `ArrayList`.
Can someone, please, give me a rough estimate? Or maybe there's even an appropriate comparison table like [this one](http://www.asjava.com/core-java/time-consuming-operations-statistics-in-java/). I'd appreciate that.

Thank you.

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: You'd better go for a better architecture instead of trying to micro-optimize field access.

Comment: @sturcotte06 Do I get it right, that in my case all performance gains and losses are equally negligible and not worth taking into account?

Comment: @vic yeah you are right.

Comment: Searching an `ArrayList` takes time proportional to its length, so a `Map` is much better except for short bounded length lists. So I would *not* switch in this direction. +++ You're using `WeakReference`s a lot and that's pretty unusual. You should have a really good reason for doing this. +++ Try to extract some meaningful class and post it to [CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java). Make sure you read their guidelines first.

Comment: @maaartinus thanks a lot. Some general guidance was all I needed.

Answer (score 1):

> Currently my program is filled with many ugly references that often make field or method access look like this:
>
> ```
> weakReference1.get().weakReference2.get().field1.getSomeCustomObject().field2
> ```

Given that the objects involved are not *Data Transfer Objects*
this is a violation of the *law of Demeter* aka *Don't talk to Strangers* / *Tell, don't ask!*

Following this LoD principle you should move the operations working with the data in `field2` to a new method in the class `SomeCustomObject`.

Comment: Thanks. I know I need to improve architecture, I'm trying to figure out in what way it should be improved.